# How to disable ngTouch conditionally and fallback to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

How can I use **ngTouch** but *selectively disable* it for some elements? That is, for certain elements I'd like to use the original `ngClick` directive instead of the one that ngTouch provides. Something like this:

```
 <button ng-click-original="myClickFn()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue is that once you include `ngTouch` module in the dependency its version of `ngClick` `ngTouch.directive('ngClick'` will override the original ngClickDirective of angular core. So all the clicks will be handled by ngTouch's version of `ng-click` so you would need to decorate the ngCLick in your module to handle your scenario. I can think of couple of approaches here:-

**Approach 1 -  Create your own directive**

How about creating an `ng-click-orig` probably don't prefix it with `ng` since it is a custom directive.

```
.directive('ngClickOrig', ['$parse', function($parse) {
      return {
        compile: function($element, attr) {
          var fn = $parse(attr["ngClickOrig"]);
          return function handler(scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function(event) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
              });
            });
          };
        }
     };
 }]);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ynbqIW?p=preview)**

---

**Approach 2:- With decorator for ng-Click directive**

Another way create a decorator on ngClickDirective, look for specific attribute say `notouch` and perform regular click or use the original one provided by ngTouch.

```
.config(function($provide){
   //Create a decoration for ngClickDirective   
   $provide.decorator('ngClickDirective', ['$delegate','$parse', function($delegate, $parse) {
        //Get the original compile function by ngTouch
        var origValue = $delegate[0].compile();
        //Get set the compiler
        $delegate[0].compile = compiler;
        //return augmented ngClick
        return $delegate;

       /*Compiler Implementation*/
       function compiler(elm, attr){
          //Look for "notouch" attribute, if present return regular click event, 
          //no touch simulation
          if(angular.isDefined(attr.notouch)){
            var fn = $parse(attr["ngClick"]);
            return function handler(scope, element) {
              element.on('click', function(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                  fn(scope, {$event:event});
                });
              });
            }
          }
          //return original ngCLick implementation by ngTouch
          return origValue;
         }
   }]);
});
```

*Just as a note decorator will not run until the directive is used for the first time and it will run only once.*

Example Usage:-

```
   <button ng-click="myClickFn()" notouch>click me</button> <-- see notouch attribute -->
   <button ng-click="myClickFnTouch()">click me</button>
```

**[Demo-Decorator](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CkJzBuQgQqjW6mUgjc6?p=preview)**