# How to fall back angular-touch ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angular-touch

The angular-touch ngClick directive's documentation say

> This directive can fall back to using an ordinary click event, and so
>   works on desktop browsers as well as mobile.

but doesn't explain how. Looking at source code I did'nt find any provider that i can customize.

I think this question isn't the same as the [26147584](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147584/how-to-disable-ngtouch-conditionally-and-fallback-to-ng-click) because i didn't need a selective solution, but the one mentioned on source code documentation.

Comment: I wonder, why you need the original one instead of the angular touch one ?

Comment: Because I need only swipe directive and the touch ngClick directive does a lot of stuff that i don't need

Comment: Are you really sure you don't need it ? My ng-click functions on mobile devices usually fire twice when i don't use ngTouch's ng-click.